# The derivation of the distribution of F-statistics in Hansen's textbook

Tags: econometrics

[image]

In Hansen's Econometrics textbook chapter 5 on normal regression model, he claims that
$$\textbf{e}'(\textbf{M}_1 - \textbf{M})\textbf{e} \sim \chi^2_q$$.
How to derive this result?

Comment: When $A$ is symmetric and idempotent, $A$ = $XDX'$, where $X'X=I$ and $D$ is diagonal with its elements 1 or 0. If $e\sim N(0,I)$, then $X'e \sim N(0, X'X) = N(0,I)$, so the elements of $X'e$ are iid standard normal. Finally, $e'Ae = e'XDX'e$ is a squared sum of independent standard normal variables, thus a $\chi^2$. The dof is the same as the number of unitary eigenvalues of $A$. That said, something is wrong in the text: $e$ can't be $N(0,I)$; it should be that $\sigma^{-2} e'(M_1-M)e\sim \chi^2_q$.